# Is it acceptable to post a 10-page long answer which includes a link to an unrelated post from the same author?

Tags: discussion, answers, spam, self-promotion

> **Edit:** there was an edit since I asked this question, but the relevant post is still accessible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56916752/2).

This question is about [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56916752/2) to this question: [Lambda Precourse Javascript Loops, Help creating loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916544/lambda-precourse-javascript-loops-help-creating-loops).

This answer has many wrong points:

- It spans about > 10 pages. (according to me, it is about the `for` loop, which should take less than 3 sentences to explain)
- The post contains a lot of code. Most content of this answer contains code (22 code snippets, more than 200 lines of JavaScript) which, in fact, yield the same result.
- Some code examples from this answer may be considered identical if it is not looked at carefully.
- I'm not able to see if it answers the question:

  > I know how to make a simple loop, but I don't know how to "reassign" the `var` count.

As, the post contains a link to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230733/node-js-promise-within-promise-within-promise/55232156#55232156). It is completely unrelated to the answered question, as it is about Node.js promises. The author of the linked answer seems to be same as the author of the first answer.

**Questions:**

- Should a flag be used or the special "in need of moderation intervention"?
- If the post has to be flagged, which type of flag would be appropriate? Are "spam" and/or "not an answer" useful in that case?

Comment: It's definitely an answer. It has a lot of (IMHO) unnecessary code snippets, but that doesn't warrant a flag. The poster was just trying to be very thorough because the OP was new at coding

Comment: To my eyes, the excessive length and the irrelevant link are separate problems that have little to do with each other. (Also, neither of them calls for a flag.)

Comment: You probably want to add "specific-post" tag... It is perfectly fine to do what you've described in general - [C# What is NRE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186/477420) is about that size and with enough links to other posts.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This is a different case, because this is an answer to a highly-voted question, and the answer is marked as **community wiki** - which means edits are accessible to [everyone with 100+ rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki). The same applies for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/10875622): the post is very long, but most of what is explained there is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general it is perfectly acceptable to provide an answer that hits all the points mentioned in the post (10+ pages long with a lot of code and links to other answers by same the person, whether it is correctly answers the question or not <sup>1</sup>).

About specific question - it does not look like answer should be flagged.

Reasons why none of the flags apply:

- spam - Link to own answer on SO is not really promotion of a product.
- rude or abusive - definitely not - there is nothing of this kind in the post. You may consider providing unclear answer "rude", but that is not type of rudeness that should be flagged.
- NAA - post definitely tries to answer the question and somewhat relates to the (possible) topic in the question. Not "thanks", "another question",...
- VLQ - post definitely is readable, contains clear code and description.
- in need of moderator intervention - you can vote on quality, comment. The only reason this flag would apply if you looked through posts by the same author and found some strange pattern - i.e. every question has link to another unrelated question (this is suggestion, I have not investigated this particular case)

In similar cases you should downvote or comment the answer yourself, there is no need to involve mods yet. It is always good idea to consider if the question is the cause of a long confusing answer and act on the question too.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Indeed technically incorrect answers should be moderated, but it does not mean it is not acceptable to provide one. Author may misunderstood the question or suggested bad practice - downvotes/comments can take care of that. Making long posts not allowed just because  sometime they are not the best/correct answers is not something I want to see happening.</sub>